# Configuration inheritance and resolution

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have some trouble with gradle and I don't know why this doesn't work:

Project A with 2 sub-project B and C

B and C have a configuration named `masterConfiguration` and `superConfiguration` (who extend masterConfiguration)

I add some dependencies in both.

When I do this:

```groovy
configurations.superConfigurations.resolvedConfiguration.files
```

All is fine, and I have all files from `superConfiguration` and `masterConfiguration`.

Now, the problem.

I create a configuration (projectAConfiguration) in the project A (the rootProject).
This configuration extends `superConfiguration` from B and C.
I add no new dependencies in this one.

If I do this:

```groovy
configurations.projectAConfiguration.resolvedConfiguration.files
```

I have nothing. I don't understand why?

settings.gradle =>

```groovy
include 'B'
include 'C'
```

build.gradle =>

```groovy
configurations {
  projectAConfiguration
}

def rootConfiguration = configurations.projectAConfiguration

subprojects {
  configurations {
    masterConfiguration
    superConfiguration {
      extendsFrom masterConfiguration
    }
  }

  rootConfiguration.extendsFrom configurations.superConfiguration

  dependencies {
    masterConfiguration 'group:artifactid:version'
    superConfiguration 'anotherGroup:anotherArtifactid:version'
  }

  //ALL IS OK
  println configurations.superConfiguration.resolvedConfiguration.files

}

  //NOT OK
  println configurations.projectAConfiguration.resolvedConfiguration.files
```

Comment: This is the first time I've seen a configuration in one project extending from another project, and I wouldn't be surprised if this is not a supported use case. What are you trying to do? Maybe we can help you find another way.

Comment: In some simple word :
i want to resolve a configuration from subproject in the project A task. I have a warning from gradle who say : it's not safe. 

The documentation about it say : create a configuration who extends other one and resolve your configuration

Answer (score 0):

You can get the configuration of a sub-project just by referencing the project in the same way as you would declare a dependency to it. You don't need to create another configuration that extends it.

For example (Groovy DSL):

```groovy
// Root project A
task printConfigurationB { 
  doLast { 
    println project("B").configurations.superConfiguration.resolve()
  }
}
```

Comment: This cas works but a warning come :

This configuration :B:superConfiguration was resolved without accessing the project in a safe manner. This behaviour has beed deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 6.0

Answer (score 0):

I have solve my problem with this solution :

Add task on all subproject.

```groovy
task resolveMyConf {
  doLast {
    it.ext.confResolve = it.configurations.superConfiguration..resolvedConfiguration.files
  }
}
```

and in the project A

```groovy
task resolveAllConf {
  suprojects.each {
    dependsOn it.resolveMyConf 
  }

  doLast {
    //and now, we can collect all task result
  }
}
```

I don't know if it's good, maybe there is a better solution. But it works.